# How to change drop-down to drop-up menu

Tags: drop-down-menu

I guess I am not the first one asking this question but I am at loss and have no idea how to do this. (there is a banner above the menu but I want to keep this picture private) What should I change in this css so the menu can go upward? Please help I need it for a project and the deadline is today till midnight.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#menu {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1010px;
}
#menu ul { 
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 line-height:50px;
}
#menu li { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 background:#F00;
}
#menu ul li a { 
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-style:oblique;
 text-decoration:none;
 height: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#menu ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 52px;
 visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{ 
 visibility:visible;
}

#menu li:hover { 
 background:#999;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000" leftmargin="50px" rightmargin="50px">
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
   <li><a><font size="+3">Paranoja</font></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#opis etiudy">Opis etiudy</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#pomysl">Skąd się wziął pomysł etiudy</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#inspiracje">Insiracje</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#obejrzyj">Obejrzyj "Paranoję"</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#caly film">Link do całego filmu</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a><font size="+3">Obsada</font></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#aktorzy">Aktorzy</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#tworcy">Twórcy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a><font size="+3">Reżyser</font></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#o mnie">O mnie</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a><font size="+3">Galeria</font></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#kadry">Kadry z filmu</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#making">Making of</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a><font size="+3">Kontakt</font></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#mail">Email</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#fb">Media społecznościowe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>

  </body></html>
```

Comment: Plot twist: use `transform:rotate(180deg)` ;)

Comment: I have used someone elses answer, but thank you either way for trying to help. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you only need to make a small change. When you set the `ul` `top` value, you can just use `bottom` instead. This will cause the bottom of the drop down to align with the top of the menu button.

```
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 52px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aLy6aazn/)

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I love you mate no homo tho. Once again thank you very much, you are a lifesaver it works perfectly. I don't believe it was something THAT simple ^^ Want a beer or something? :) Have a wonderfull day!